# How does Schedulers.from(this.executor) work?

Tags: rx-java

I am new to RXJAVA and I am trying to understand its basics.

I would like to understand what happens underneath when I do `Schedulers.from(executorservice)` (ExecutorService created out of java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool).

In our application we are using the above code snippet and when I take a thread dump, I could see two extra threads being created `RxScheduledExecutorPool-1` and `RxScheduledExecutorPool2`.

Please help me in understanding its flow.

Comment: It is due to a set of helper threads: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/schedulers/GenericScheduledExecutorService.java

Comment: Hi @akarnokd                                                                                          
Thank you so much for your reply. But I couldnt understand the use and purpose of these helper threads. Is there any document available, where i can understand what it does?

Comment: Read the JavaDocs of these internal components. They were there to help with timed schedules. Note though that 1.x is no longer maintained or supported.